# Cannot save file in 'tmp' folder

Tags: python, heroku

It's the first time I use Heroku and it's ephemeral file system. I have a python script that requires a temporary folder to write some files while the script runs.

What I have done first: create a 'tmp' folder in my heroku root folder following this logic:

```
mkdir tmp
touch tmp/.keep
git add tmp/.keep
git commit -m "Add tmp directory to app repository."
```

I have also created a simple python script to store a dataframe into a text file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Name': {0: 'John', 1: 'Luc', 2: 'Steph'}, 'Gender': {0: 'Male', 1: 'Male', 2: 'Female'}, 'Age': {0: 55, 1: 47, 2: 20}} )
df.to_csv('tmp/df.txt')
```

In the Heroku CLI, I run that script with:

```
heroku run python createfile.py
```

After the script has run, I go to the 'tmp' folder using bash:

```
heroku run bash
cd tmp
ls
```

But the folder is empty, while I would expect the *df.txt* to be there.
Is there any step I am missing? Or do I need a paying Heroku account to be able to write to the tmp folder? Do I have to chmod this folder first?

**edit**: I did some more tests, and it seems that the file gets correctly written to the tmp folder. It's just that it cannot be seen / gets deleted when using the 'heroku run bash' command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku doesn't behave like a virtual server. By design, dynos are disposable.

Every time you use `heroku run` you access a [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) that is discarded as soon as the command ends (or you log out in the case of something interactive like `bash`). You are running your `createfile.py` script and `bash` in two completely unrelated instances that do not share a filesystem.

I'm not clear on what you are trying to achieve, but in general you can keep temporary "working" things in the memory of a single process for a short period of time. Anything you wish to persist beyond that scope must be saved outside of your dyno, e.g. in a client-server database like PostgreSQL or an object store like Azure Blob Storage.

Note that this model is a deliberate architectural decision and it impacts all tiers of Heroku dynos. Upgrading to a paid plan won't change anything.